# Even after installing jenkins as a windows service, i have to start it through command line before accessing it through browser

Tags: jenkins, windows-services

I have installed jenkins as windows service but every time after starting the machine i have to execute it through command line using $ java -jar jenkins.war

I am not able to directly open it into web browser at http://localhost:8080/

Am i missing something? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the service Startup Type 'Automatic' ?

Comment: Yes, the service Startup Type is  'Automatic'. But still its not starting automatically.

Comment: http://mirrors.jenkins.io/windows/latest

Comment: Thanks Barney for your response. The issue is fixed now. I have changed the service properties. In service properties -> Log On->Select Local system account and select the checkbox for allow the service to interact with desktop

Comment: @sushilbolwar: thanks for your comment, that seems to have solved the issue for me. You should post it as a reply and mark it as accepted (which I'll be happy to upvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed now. I have changed the service properties. In service properties -> Log On->Select Local system account and select the checkbox for allow the service to interact with desktop

Answer (score 1):

- Copy original 'jenkins.war' into 'jenkins' directory and restart service
- Clear the Windows event viewer logs for Application and System
- Please ensure your services are running and up
- Firewall Issue:The easiest way to track down firewall issues is to use tcpdump. Just run the following command on the Jenkins server, which is trying to connect to the slave.

More Info on firewall part:
By default, Windows Firewall prevents the TCP connections necessary to make this mechanism work. The firewall on the slave must allow the following exceptions (see List of TCP&UDP port numbers):

TCP Port 135 (DCE/RPC Locator service)
TCP Port 139 (NetBIOS Session Service)
TCP Port 445 (Windows shares)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllhost.exe (dllhost.exe seems to use a random port number)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaw.exe (Jenkins also uses a random port number)
File and Printer sharing (TCP 139, TCP 445, UDP 137, UDP 138 (possibly only a subset of these is required))

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your response. The issue is fixed now. I have changed the service properties. In service properties -> Log On->Select Local system account and select the checkbox for allow the service to interact with desktop